# removeChild not working within stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to remove a html element within a page I do not own within my ipad app.

Using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString I can return the element I want:

```
NSString *source = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var parentEl = document.getElementById('header');parentEl.childNodes[5].innerHTML;"];
```

But when trying to remove it I can not:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var parentEl = document.getElementById('header');parentEl.removeChild(parentEl.childNodes[5]);"];
```

But if I run this code in safari remotely from the developer tools it works fine, which has me a little stumped!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is because you are missing the object off which you are accessing the childNodes collection:

```
parentEl = document.getElementById('header');
parentEl.removeChild(parentEl.childNodes[5]);
```

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong code in I did have the object in prior to trying pretty much everything in desperation!